# Python: how to select the values (stored in a vector) of a row in a Table?

Tags: python

I am new in Python and I have to make a table. I have to select the table rows one at a time, depending on the desired selection. Each line is composed by three values. The latter values are then used in further equations. The problem is that I cannot switch between table lines when run the code. Is someone can help me?
Thanks in advance.

Here below the code:

## D is one specific Table line, by default the line selected is called D

```
class glass_load:   

    def __init__(self,cat='D'):  
        self.cat=cat

    def Table_csi(self,):
        if self.cat=='C' or self.cat=='D' or self.cat=='F':
            csi=[0.7,0.7,0.6]
        elif self.cat=='H':
            csi=[0.0,0.0,0.0]
        return(csi)
```

## When I run the code I select the line with the name H

cat='H'           #  Line H

print('Table csi:',test_glass.Table_csi())

## The default values stored in the line D do not change Why?

Table csi: [0.7, 0.7, 0.6]

Comment: Hi chrisis, could you please explain in a more detail what are you trying to achieve (expected output of your program)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should handle the case where 'cat' is not C,D.F.H

```
class GlassLoad:

    def __init__(self, cat='D'):
        self.cat = cat

    def table_csi(self):
        if self.cat in ['C', 'D', 'F']:
            csi = [0.7, 0.7, 0.6]
        elif self.cat == 'H':
            csi = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
        else:
            csi = [-1, -1, -1]
        return csi


glass_load1 = GlassLoad('H')
glass_load2 = GlassLoad('D')
glass_load3 = GlassLoad('Z')

print(glass_load1.table_csi())
print(glass_load2.table_csi())
print(glass_load3.table_csi())
```

Output

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[0.7, 0.7, 0.6]
[-1, -1, -1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass cat as 'H' to the constructor of glass_load when you create its object:

```
test_glass = glass_load(cat='H')
```

The cat variable you have outside the class is different from the cat that you have inside the class, and as such, assigning it any value will not affect your result. Within your Table_csi function, you accessed self.cat, which refers to the class's own cat variable, not the external one.

Comment: Please consider marking this as the solution if it answers your question

Comment: Hi, how do you do that?

Comment: You can click on the grey check mark to accept an answer. Also consider upvoting all the answers you find helpful. This can be done by clicking on the grey upward arrow. For more information, please refer https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work